# background-image won't show on phone browser

Tags: iphone, css, background-image

I have the following CSS in order to get an image on my page background, and a color around it.

```
#home{text-align:center;background:Red url('/Content/image.png') no-repeat fixed center;}
```

When I run it on my computer with any browser (I prefer Chrome), everything is fine. However, when I open the website on my phone (also using Chrome), I only see the background color, not the image. However, as soon as I remove the center part (background position), I can see it.

Any idea?

Comment: try `background-image` instead

Comment: I've done them all separately (background-color, background-image, background-repeat...) and same result.

Comment: What model of the phone? And did you try to use relative paths?

Comment: iPhone 4S. As I've said in my OP, it does show when I don't use the center property so path isn't an issue here.

Comment: I hope, here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183467/css-background-position-not-working-in-mobile-safari-iphone-ipad

Answer (score 3):

After some searching, I found that images wider than 1024px don't display on iDevices. I used a media query to change the background, like this:

```
@media all and (max-width:900px), (max-device-width:900px){
body{
background-image: url('smaller-image.gif');
}
}
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: I've been messing around with my CSS for hours now trying to get a background image to display on iOS7 or older devices with no luck. I changed my image to 1024px in width (from 3000px) and now it works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I faced a same problem, then I applied `background:url("../img/pic1.jpg") no-repeat center;` its working you can try if you faced problem in ios.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays it doesn't really matter whether picture is wider than 1024px. The issue for me that caused not displaying background-image was: `background-attachment: fixed;`

In this case, just change this line to `background-attachment: scroll;` with @media query