# scroll of div over body does not work on iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone

I have a website with a menu. Sometimes the menu content is overflowing it's container and i need it to to be scrollable.
It works fine on a pc. Yet on an iphone what happens is that when i try to scroll the menu, it scrolls the whole body instead. As a result, the entire view is being dragged down/up reveling a grey area at the top/bottom of the screen.
This happens mostly in portrait mode, for some reason. In landscape, if i go easy on the swiping, i am able to scroll the menu content alone while the rest of the body stays put.

Can anyone help with that?

Thank you!!

---

```
<html>
<style>
   #menu {
      overflow: scroll;
   }
</style>
<body>
   <div id="menu">
      --content--
   </div>
   <div id="mainPage">
      --content--
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you put your code uo?

Comment: not really... it's a part of a really huge web-app...

Comment: Ok, when you to mobile is your menu a side drawer style one, which when you scroll you only want the menu to scroll and not the rest of your page?

Comment: yes. But i feel like i need to be more specific:
I use jQuery to disable the scroll of the page as the menu opens. Yet there is a feature of the Safari browser (i guess) to scroll the entire web page leaving a gray spacing, when you try to scroll more then the page's height. THAT is what prevents me from scrolling the menu's content, I think.

Comment: Are you menu (what you want to scroll) and you content (what you don't want to scroll) in the same container? If so this could ne your problem. I prefer to have menu outside of the container, then you can just do overflow: scroll on the menu without having to worry about any content scrolling that you don't want to.

Comment: no. I will now post an edit to my question to try and guideline how my html looks like

Comment: You could just add a class with javascript/jquery to <div id="mainPage"></div> when the menu is open with position: fixed set on it. So when <div id="menu"></div> is open it will have position: scroll for its style and <div id="mainPage"></div> will have position fixed. You can remove this class you added when the menu is closed so you will can rid of the position fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This link could possibly help you... Hope it helps and good luck! :)

[Background position not functioning as expected on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183467/css-background-position-not-working-in-mobile-safari-iphone-ipad)

Or just add this in the div's class

background-position-x: 50%; (This will hopefully resolve your issue with the Safari browser)
background-position-y: 0%;  (This will hopefully resolve your issue with the Safari browser)
background-position: center top; (This should work on the PC)