# HTML email background-color not working on mobile but works on desktop

Tags: html, email, gmail, background-color

Please can someone help with this issue I'm having.

I'm trying to create an HTML email using tables and have followed some tutorials to get the hang of the layout etc.

But I'm having issues with the background colors when i use litmus to send the email to my gmail account on my phone/laptop.

I want the background-color to be black, green font and a red border.

Laptop - the email shows as i want it to look with the correct colors/layout.

Mobile - the background-color is white but everything else is correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I've attached the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>HTML EMAIL</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
   
  
<table width="100%" height="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="black">

            <table style="width:320px; border:solid 2px red; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" >
              <tr>
                <td style="color:green; filter:brightness(200%);text-align:center;">HTML EMAIL</td>
                 </tr>
              
               </table>

            <table width="600" align="center" >

            </table>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to look to this, it may help you. [this is the same as your error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183467/css-background-position-not-working-in-mobile-safari-iphone-ipad)

Comment: It seems that the color black may not be recognised : try color=#000000

Comment: your code is working in my Samsung A31 on Chrom, Brave and Internet browser. it might be your phone problem.

Try style="background-color: #000";

Comment: Thank you all for your responses! @Mehrwarz - thanks so much for checking the code, it must be my phone because gmail is showing it correctly on desktop and also through the website on my phone. It's just the gmail app that isnt working. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

On my phone battery saver was turned on, which removed all the backgrounds. Check that.