# "hover" effect using single tap on iPad (similar to SO)

Tags: jquery, ipad, hover

If you've ever used StackOverflow on the iPad, you may have noticed that in order to delete a comment, you:

- first tap the comment field
- the field gets highlighted in gray and the delete icon appears in gray
- you can then tap on the icon to delete the comment

On a desktop, this process is more straightforward because the mouse can hover over the comment, hiding and making the icon visible on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` via jQuery `.css`.

I have already set up a posts and comments system on my blog that has this functionality very similar to SO running on a desktop, but I wonder how to achieve SO's iPad functionality.

Any ideas how SO makes the single tap act as a hover on the comments?

Comment: To echo Cory, I *think* iOS (or, rather Mobile Safari) will automatically handle this in many cases. The key is to find the particular case that it handles the conversion automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

Any time I have coded anything that responds to mouseenter in jQuery or Mootools, the iPad immediately converted this behavior to a single click.  This includes links that would normally take you to another page on a single click.  Is this not the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: good point @cory, i just checked again and notice that when i tap on the comments container (which I use to trigger the icon visibility on mouseenter) nothing happens. but if i tap on an unrelated link within that container (eg, "add comment", similar to SO) then the icon appears -- maybe i need to change things around in my code

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery you could write a click event:

```
$(".comment").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

And create some [iPad-only CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678297/how-to-target-css-for-ipad-but-exclude-safari-4-desktop-using-a-media-query) like this:

```
.comment .delete
{
    display: none;
}

.comment.clicked .delete
{
    display: inline;
}
```

which would work if your html was something like this:

```
<div class="comment">... <a class="delete">Delete</a></div>
```

and wire up these into their own ipad.css and ipad.js files and include them in your `<head>`

```
<!--[if iPad]>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="ipad.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="ipad.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/pqLXS/

Comment: thx @hunter - now the issue is that on desktop i would need the red delete from your example to show on hover (mouseenter) -- which I already have implemented -- but on iPad 'delete' would need to show on click -- any idea how to adapt your example to this?