# Change Font Size On Detection Of IPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, joomla

I need a simple solution for changing the font size to slightly bigger when my joomla site is viewed on an iPad. 
The solutions I have found so far involve either making a separate stylesheet, which I have done but have no idea how to activate once the page loads, or even loading a mobile version of the site, which seems overkill.
Is there not some simple javascript snippet I could use that detects the presence of an iPad and then adjusts the font size accordingly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ipad-specific-css/) link, you should set your font-size in the css. You can also see [How to target CSS for iPad but exclude Safari 4 desktop using a media query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678297/how-to-target-css-for-ipad-but-exclude-safari-4-desktop-using-a-media-query) which may be of help.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:1024px) and (width:1024px) {
    p {
        font-size: landscape font size
    }
}


@media screen and (max-device-width:1024px) and (width:768px) {
    p {
        font-size: portrait font size
    }
}
```